# How to check that sent email has gone out from SMTP

Tags: .net, smtp

My company is using Mailbee SMTP component for sending emails. 
They asked me to investigate how to know when the email has gone out from SMTP's server queue.

As i know, regular smtp process is following:

-Mailbee connects with SMTP server 
-Mailbee sends to the SMTP the recipient and body of email 
-The SMTP server puts the email to the sending queue 
-When its time to send the email, the SMTP server takes it from the queue and connects with target SMTP server 
-The SMTP server sends the email to the target smtp 
-the SMTP server removes the email from the sending queue.

I want to know the moment when the email has gone from the sending queue. 
I need it to set a flag in my internal database. The flag means that the message has gone from my SMTP server.

What's the best way how to check it ?

Comment: Usually the server keeps a log of activities, this information would be in it. (Note also that SMTP is a store-and-forward protocol, so that your SMTP server is not necessarily connecting to the target server; the mail can be delivered through an unspecified number of intermediate SMTP servers)

Answer (score 0):

Hi look at this article: http://www.iislogs.com/steveschofield/want-help-with-iis-smtp-service-please-enable-logging

it describe how to enable the SMTP log in your IIS

Comment: Thank for your answer. I'm not using IIS SMTP. Instead I'm using SMTP of the Microsoft Exchange server